# Access to previous steep Html

Tags: elm

I am learning Elm and I seems that you make a new VirtualDOM every `view` "frame".

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
```

There is no reference to the previous generated `Html` value, so there is no option to update it (in a functional way). You must rebuild it from scratch. This is highly inefficient.

How can you reuse the old frame and only update changed nodes (and their ancestors)?

**EDIT**

As an answers points, Elm have `Html.Lazy`. With it and the clever runtime you can avoid repeating most of the work and data allocation (useless garbage collector pressure is a bad thing), but at the expenses of adding a lot of cognitive load on the programmer.

Reasoning about strictness/laziness on the term level (instead of on the type level) is error prone (see Haskell and `seq`).

The perfect solution would be a `view` function with this signature:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg -> Html Msg
```

This way you have access to the previous frame VirtualDOM and you can share as much of it with the new frame data structure as you want.

Is this option available? If not, why not?

Comment: Elm only updates the DOM with what has changed. [See this blog post for more info](http://elm-lang.org/blog/blazing-fast-html)

Comment: @ChadGilbert This is with regard to the real DOM, but before that it must construct the VirtualDOM. If this structure consists of thousands of nodes it will, at least, overload the garbage collector. This isn't optimal.

Comment: "This is highly inefficient." It's efficient enough for everyone successfully using Elm. Are you having a specific optimization problem we can help address?

Comment: @z5h It puts a lot of pressure on the garbage collector, without which Elm would be even faster than it already is. What is even more important, you would avoid having to reason laziness, a very difficult problem.

Comment: @user3368561 having a garbage collected language puts pressure on a garbage collector. Should we be using C and hand-allocating memory for web UI?

Comment: @z5h That is nonsense. Having a garbage collector is perfectly fine, and at the same time, it isn't an excuse to not be disciplined. Allocating superfluous data is suboptimal with or without garbage collector.

Comment: @user3368561 I was hoping to help you see your original statement of "This is highly inefficient." was similarly nonsensical. Elm performs better than frameworks which allow mutability. https://evancz.github.io/react-angular-ember-elm-performance-comparison/

Answer (score 1):

As you know, Elm uses a "virtual DOM". Your program outputs lightweight objects that describe the DOM structure you want, and the virtual DOM implementation "diffs" the current and new structure, adding, modifying, and removing elements/attributes/properties as required.

Of course, there is a small performance penalty to using a virtual DOM over directly manipulating the DOM, but the difference doesn't matter in most web applications. If you find that your application has poor performance in the view function, there are several ways to improve performance, such as [`Html.Lazy`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html-Lazy)

Many other popular libraries use a virtual DOM, such as React, Angular, and Vue. Usually, it's easier to render your application with a virtual DOM (rather than "manually" manipulating the DOM), so many of the popular frameworks implement one.

Comment: I'm not talking about manipulating the real DOM, but the old VirtualDOM. This way you don't need to rebuild the whole tree, but only create changed nodes and their ancestors (because immutability).

Comment: I see that you have `Html.Lazy`. Its better than nothing, but explicitly manipulating thunks sound to low-level and error-prone for a functional programming language. The perfect option would be a `view` function with this signature: `view : Model -> Html Msg -> Html Msg`. This way you can share as much of the old frame data as you want without the need to resort to strange features as explicit thunks.

Comment: In most cases, re-creating the DOM "description" doesn't noticeably affect performance. When it does, you can use Html.Lazy. Your code doesn't change much in order to use Html.Lazy, it's handled by the virtual DOM.